# Overriding Properties with Attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, attributes

Let's say I have 3 classes (Parent, Son and Daughter). I'd like Son and Daughter to use the Name getter method of Parent, but I'd like to apply different attributes for each child class, respectively.

```
public class Parent {

private string name;

public string Name { 
  get { return this.name; }
  set { this.name = value != null ? value.trim() : null; }
}

}
```

and Son...

```
public class Son : Parent { 
  [SonAttribute]
  public string Name { // keep parent behavior }
  }
}
```

Same `Name` getter method for daughter but with `[Daughter]` attribute.

Can I do this?

Comment: @TGH - thank you for your answer (looks like it was deleted). I chose p.s.w.g because I don't fully understand the `new` keyword with respect to a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `Name` virtual on `Parent`:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public virtual string Name 
    { 
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value != null ? value.trim() : null; }
    }
}
```

You can always do this:

```
public class Son : Parent 
{
    [SonAttribute]
    public override string Name 
    { 
        get { return base.Name; }
        set { base.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

If the `Name` property is not virtual you'll be creating a new property which *hides* the property on the base type, which is probably not what you want. See [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173153.aspx) for details.

Comment: Will the `name` field of the Son and Daughter classes belong to the Father or the children?

Comment: @Kevin The private field will belong to the `Parent` class.